# Why does changing the name of an Entity change program behavior?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a Code First EF model setup, and I was experimenting adding records using both entities and ID values.  Not shown here, but "above" this code is where I setup and added to the context other entities (eg, uCarParents, uAlice, etc)

Then I hit this block of code.  Note that the only time I call context.SaveChanges() is the one at the end of this block.

```
        var uba = new List<UserBooleanAttribute>
        {
            new UserBooleanAttribute {UserAttribute= uCarParents, User = uAlice},
            new UserBooleanAttribute {UserAttribute = uCarTeens, User = uBob},
            new UserBooleanAttribute {UserAttributeID = 3, UserID = 1},
            new UserBooleanAttribute {UserAttributeID = 4, UserID = 2}
        };
        uba.ForEach(ua => context.UserBooleanAttributes.Add(ua));

        context.SaveChanges();
```

SaveChanges works, my Assertions pass.  Then someone pointed out to me that the name of UserBooleanAttribute should really be **ProjectBooleanAttribute**.  So I changed that and then I get an FK exception on SaveChanges.

Somewhat perplexed, I put a SaveChanges() above this block and then it started working again. My suspicion was that the problem was adding new UserBooleanAttributes using the ID's was somehow involved.  Indeed, if I replaced those two lines with passing in the UserAttribute and User instead of the ID's, it started working without the extra SaveChanges.

But that got me to wondering why it was working in the first place.

So I started to do more testing by renaming BooleanAttribute **XXXBooleanAttribute** it works.  So does **VVVBooleanAttribute**, but **UUUBooleanAttribute** does NOT work.

This behavior is rather strange to say the least.  I'm just guessing, but it looks like EF (and thus SQL Server) might be updating the tables in a certain order based upon how class is named.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening.  EF makes assumptions about the relationships between the tables based on how you name the ID field.  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx

Comment: Well, I did rename my ID accordingly, so shouldnt I see my original behavior?

Comment: I would look what the column names and FK relationships are in the tables.  That will give you an indication of what EF thinks is going on.